# Storing Different Kind Of Files in iCloud Through an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

Basically we can store document formatted files in iCloud while running an IOS app....
but can we store some thing else like images,sqlite files in iCloud...Through app?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: yes u can , check core data with icloud

Comment: is it possible without including core data...

Comment: U can send images through documents

Comment: thank you...can u suggest the sample code.....

Comment: there is library for it , search google with the keywords uploading an image using icloud ...